# refresh waypoints on directions_changed

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I made myself a routes manager with a couple of options (like avoidTolls, travelMode, avoidHighways, waypoints) and draggable routes.

I Created `var lastRequest = []` to store `DirectionsRequest properties` from the last render.

The code looks like this:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var directions = parseDirections(response, mode, tolls)
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response)
    }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    refreshReq(directionsDisplay.getDirections())
})

function refreshReq(response)
{
    //
}
```

I'm stuck finding a solution to refresh on `directions_changed` my `lastRequest['waypoints']` with new data from a `response` so my script will be able to store a waypoints object and redo `lastRequest` any time I want.

Difficulty comes when I take from `response` the waypoints Array like I need.

**Tried couple variants:**
`lastRequest['waypoints'] = response['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['via_waypoints']`
but that was not that.

Next step was to regenerate every waypoint one by one with `new google.maps.LatLng()` but for some reason not worked even after I pushed them in array with eval().

Changed stopover to false/true, tried different things but nothing, must be missing something.

Comment: Can you please answer your own question. Just copy paste your answer into the box below and mark as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

points js array that I generated by php needed refresh from via_waypoints

```
for (var p in req.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints)
  points[p]['location'] = req.routes[0].legs[0].via_waypoints[p]
```